# Map or Fit (x, y) Coordinates to 2D Python List As Best As Possible

Tags: python, arrays, mapping, points

I have a list of objects that I have mapped on an xy-plane based on similarity. The points for these objects are stored in a 2D python list:

```
>>> points
[[x1, x2, ... , xn],
 [y1, y2, ... , yn]]
```

The coordinates are floating point numbers and somewhat outline a square on a scatter plot. This is an example of 2000 objects mapped on a plane:

[example of plotted points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u3LJ.png)

I am trying to "fit" these points into a two-dimensional list in Python. Essentially, I want to keep the relative similarities of the points, but map them to a 2D array. For example, let's say I have these four points that form a perfect square:

```
(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), and (2, 2)
```

I want an algorithm that will map them (as best as possible, obviously not perfectly unless the points form a perfectly filled square) to a 2D list like this:

```
[[(2, 1), (2, 2)], 
 [(1, 1), (1, 2)]]
```

If I have n points, then the 2D list generated will have m by m dimensions where m*m >= n. Any unused spots in the list will have "None" inside of it.

Here is some code I wrote attempting a solution. I pass the function a list of objects and a 2D list of their xy-coordinates, respectively. I then calculate the upper and lower bound in the x and y direction, and compute the "grids" that each spot in the list will represent based on the size of the matrix I am trying to fill. Then, I iterate through each point, and try an place it in the closest mapped spot I can find.

I try the point itself, and if it is already full, I search the perimeter around the spot in the matrix. If all those are full, I increase the "radius" of the perimeter to check until I find a spot.

This has two issues:
1) I know this is not as accurate of a mapping I could create, but I searched online and cannot find any other ideas.
2) Sometimes, this code never finishes and can't find the proper open spot. I know I can fix this bug somewhere in the calculation of the perimeter, but I figured I best spend my time looking for a more optimal solution. Hence, here I am!

This is my first SO post as well, so apologies if I didn't follow proper procedure.

Here is the code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
from math import ceil, sqrt

def insert_nearest(lst, obj, i, j, N):
    if lst[i][j] == None: # see if "ideal" spot is empty
        lst[i][j] = obj
        return
    yu = i - 1 # top of box
    yd = i + 1 # bottom of box
    xl = j - 1 # left of box
    xr = j + 1 # right of bog
    while True:
        to_try = [(yu, x) for x in range(xl, xr+1)] + \
                 [(yd, x) for x in range(xl, xr+1)] + \
                 [(y, xl) for y in range(yu+1, yd)] + \
                 [(y, xr) for y in range(yu+1, yd)] # "perimeter" points to check
        for coord in to_try: # check around perimeter for any empty spots
            try: # in case index is out of range
                if lst[coord[0]][coord[1]] == None:
                    lst[coord[0]][coord[1]] = obj
                    return
            except:
                continue
        # if perimeter is full, increase "raduis" of box and try again
        yu -= 1
        yd += 1
        xl -= 1
        xr += 1

def build_matrix(objList, points):
    N = ceil(sqrt(len(objList)))
    matrix = [[None]*N]*N

    xinc = (max(points[0]) - min(points[0])) / N # grid lines in x direction
    yinc = (max(points[1]) - min(points[1])) / N # grid lines in y direction

    for i in range(len(points[0])):
        x = min(N-1, int(points[0][i] // xinc)) # map to integer spot in list
        y = min(N-1, int(points[1][i] // yinc)) # map to integer spot in list
        insert_nearest(matrix, objList[i], x, y, N)

    return matrix
```

Comment: so you want to make some kinds of "array" - actually a list of lists, and place `(y,x)` pairs into it based on the values of `y` and `x`? and each time you get a new item you potentially restructure the whole thing?

Comment: Yeah exactly, a list of lists based on the values of y and x of each point. Each time a point is inserted, it will restructure the points to some degree. However, as long as I have the relative positions as best as possible, I will still accomplish my task.

Comment: ...and these are (for example) small valued integers, so that frequently two points will have exactly the same y and therefore belong to the same row, **-or-** are they irrational floating points (e.g. 7.1112 and 7.1113) and you want to bin them to avoid having a zillion rows each with one member?

Comment: They'll be floating points and yes I'm trying to bin them as best as possible. For example, if I had 8 points along a straight line OR 8 points that make a rectangle, they'd have to fit in a 3x3 matrix (2D list) as best as possible, since 9 is the next highest perfect square.

Comment: hmmm... so this is really a programming question. there's no part of your question that's really specific to Python, except that Python happens to be the language you are currently using.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Nothing Python specific, but a programming/algorithm question. Should this be tagged or moved elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know where to move it, chances are small that someone will spontaneously write code for you. Keep trying to write it, it's the best way to learn. If you really get stuck and don't know why something doesn't work, you could try to post that along with all input data in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Oh I've heard of a place called "codereview" but I've never checked it out.

Comment: Can you post a few small sample inputs and the expected outputs? i.e. what would you expect the output to be for `points = [[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.1], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.9]]`